# (Reverse Proxy) Apache REMOTE_ADDR Returns (null)

Tags: apache-2.4, reverse-proxy, virtualhost, apache2, http-headers

I have a server that sits behind a reverse proxy that require client IP address, and to achieve that I'm trying with the lines below to add X-Forwarded-For in the request header,

```
RequestHeader set "X-Forwarded-For" %{REMOTE_ADDR}e
```

However, the above lines doesn't send the client IP address, it's sending **(null)** to the server.

This is my VirtualHost configuration

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName targetserver.com
    ServerAlias www.targetserver.com/
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    RewriteEngine On

    RequestHeader set "Host" "targetserver.com"

    RequestHeader set "X-Forwarded-For" %{REMOTE_ADDR}e
    #Header add "X-Forwarded-For" %{REMOTE_ADDR}e

    RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://targetserver.com/$1 [P,L]
    ProxyPassReverse / http://targetserver.com

</VirtualHost>
```

How to fix it?
Or, is there any other way to get client IP address?

Comment: Do you have the module `remoteip` activated?

Comment: @GeraldSchneider Yup, loaded and activated